# How to count words from window.prompt and sort them by number of apperance?

Tags: javascript

I need to count words from prompt and write them to the array. Next I have to count their appearance and sort them. 
I have code like this:

```js
let a = window.prompt("Write sentence")
a = a.split(" ")
console.log(a)
var i = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i].toUpperCase;
  let res = a[i].replace(",", "").replace(".", "")
  var count = {};
  a.forEach(function(i) {
    count[i] = (count[i] || 0) + 1;
  });
  console.log(count);
  document.write(res + "<br>")
}
```

I don't know how to connect my word with specific number for number of appearances and write this words one time. 
On the end it should look like:
a = "This sentence, this stentence, this sentence, nice."
This - 3 
Sentence - 3 
nice - 1

Comment: I've added and edited my answer as per your new edit also. Let me know is that worked for you or not?

Answer (score 1):

**If I don't misunderstood your requirements** then `Array.prototype.reduce()` and `Array.prototype.sort()` will the trick for you. *Imagine* I got the example string from your `window.prompt()`

```js
let string = `this constructor doesn't have neither a toString nor a valueOf. Both toString and valueOf are missing`;
let array = string.split(' ');
//console.log(array);
let result = array.reduce((obj, word) => {
  ++obj[word] || (obj[word] = 1); //  OR obj[word] = (++obj[word] || 1);
  return obj;
}, {});

sorted_result = Object.keys(result).sort(function(a,b){return result[a]-result[b]})
console.log(result);
console.log(sorted_result);
```

**AS PER QUESTION EDIT**

```js
let string = `This sentence, this sentence, this sentence, nice.`;
let array = string.split(' ');
array = array.map(v => v.toLowerCase().replace(/[.,\s]/g, ''))
let result = array.reduce((obj, word) => {
   ++obj[word] || (obj[word] = 1); // OR obj[word] = (++obj[word] || 1);
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I like `obj[word]=-~obj[word];` as an expression of curiosity... I suppose compilers nowadays might be able to optimise the extra side-effect away, though you could also reorder the side-effects like: `++obj[num] || (obj[num] = 1);` to transform the extra side-effect into a lazy one.

Comment: @autistic your `++obj[num] || (obj[num] = 1);` seems **cool** to me that's way edited ::)

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce. Like so:

```
const wordsArray = [...].map(w => w.toLowerCase());

const wordsOcurrenceObj = wordsAray.reduce((acc, word) => {
  if (!acc[word]) {
    acc[word] = 0;
  }

  acc[word] += 1;

  return acc;
}, {});
```

What this does is keep track of the words in an object. When a word is not there, initializes with zero. And then adds a 1 every time you encounter that word. You will end up with an object like this:

```
{
  'word': 3,
  'other': 1,
  ...
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the string is, for example, `"this constructor doesn't have neither a toString nor a valueOf. Both toString and valueOf are missing"`. You'll get some strange behaviour. Try it! To fix this you may want to pass a prototypeless object (`Object.create(null)`) as the initial value to `reduce` instead of `{}`. That way `acc[word]` won't look into the prototype because there isn't any. Or you can keep `{}` but use `acc.hasOwnPropert(word)` instead of `acc[word]`.

Comment: You are right. Feel free to edit my answer so you get the credit

Answer (score -1):

Add another loop at the end that goes over the counts and prints them:

```
 for(let word in count) {
   console.log(word + " appeared " + count[word] + " times");
 }
```

Comment: You skipped over the important bit of the question: the code that does the counting. It's full of errors: redefining `i`, `toUppercase` is a function, it is supposed to return the value instead of altering it, loop (`forEach`) inside loop (`for`), `res` being totally useless, `res` suggests splitting could be improved.

Comment: @ibrahim I think I gave the hint into the right direction, the OP will hopefully figure out the rest ...